# Eating healthy and sporting, gaining weight

Tags: diet, sports, weight

Hello this is my first post here.

I'm trying to lose weight and I'm eating healthy and do sports for at least five days a week (Running and Cycling).

I gained 100 grams in two days, what am I doing wrong?

Here's my diet:

For breakfast I have about 30 grams of Oatmeal with a bit of soy milk at lunch I eat mainly vegetables with a bit of chicken or tuna or just vegetables. For dinner I eat whole grain rice with chicken breast and again a lot of vegetables.

During the day I eat about two pieces of fruit, like an apple or kiwi and drink about 2 liters of water.

Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest you stop weighing yourself this often. Weigh at most once a week. And never ever *ever*  take the weight of that day as a cold hard fact. Weight fluctuates. Register your weighings and observe the trend. That's the only thing that's accurate. Besides that, is weight loss really the goal? Or is it fat loss? You might gain some muscle, and thus weight. Maybe you should focus more on waist line, as it is a more honest measure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Judging from your description, you're most probably doing everything correctly.

But ok, if you wanted to be absolutely sure, you really would have to precisely measure your calorie intake vs calorie expenditure (with a tool like cronometer or sth).

And as far as gaining 100 grams in 2 days goes, that's just jumping to conclusions and easily falls within normal day-to-day weight fluctuations.

I have personally lost almost 20 pounds in just 24 hours in a weight loss experiment - just to prove how much water weight can be lost (without burning off almost no body fat). And guess what...all that lost weight came back after just 2 days on my normal diet.

In other words, those 100 grams could easily mean you drank 1 extra dl of water, or that you didn't visit the toilet before weighing, or something similarly insignificant.

The only way to be sure whether or not you're gaining/losing actual body fat would be if you actually measured your body fat percentage...but even in this case, the measurements would not be precise enough to confirm what's actually happening if your weight changes by mere 100 grams.

Comment: I've found that weight can easily fluctuate by as much as 500 grams from "noise" such as how recently you've had a drink, meal, gone to the toilet etc. 100 grams is completely inconclusive. Comparing your weight daily is a pointless exercise. A better method is to weight yourself daily at the same point of your routine (e.g. always before breakfast and after morning toilet visit), with the same clothes (or lack of) and form *no conclusions* from it. Write it down and calculate the average once per week, then use that as your basis.

Answer (score -2):

According to [Beachbody](http://www.beachbody.com/beachbodyblog/fitness/ask-the-expert-why-do-you-gain-weight-when-you-start-working-out)

> Odds are that it’s not fat, but rather temporary water weight due to inflammation

When you work out your body undergoes a process called adaption where you cause microtears which heal and make your muscles stronger. As your body heals you it releases substances

> inflammatory mediators that swarm the area and perform triage, bringing in healing white blood cells and opening up blood vessels to flush out debris and toxins. There’s so much going on that the area swells up, or inflames.

It's normal and only temporary, you should notice a change in a few weeks if you stick with it :). Keep eating right and getting enough rest and your body will adapt.

> Another less-likely reason you’re gaining weight is that you’re
>   building muscle faster than you’re shedding fat.

This is also fine, just be patient and you should see results.

If you are still worried I reccommend using a food tracker like myFitnessPal to make sure you are intaking the right amount of calories and a good ratio of fats, proteins and carbohydrate. Sometimes you may think you are eating really healthily but the reality is that you are not striking as good a balance as you thought.

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). You were right to reference your answer, but there is a policy that references should be as reliable as possible. [Here is a list of suggestions](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/112/what-are-reliable-sources) for some of the sources. For more information on how the website works please visit the [help] and [meta](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/). Thanks!